# Line numbers be added when posting code

Tags: feature-request

I'm somewhat missing line numbers when code is posted.

Is there any way to have them added?

Comment: No, not currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be received with mixed interest, as the interface for Stack Exchange provides users the opportunity to post code snippets for which line numbers might not make sense.

Meta.SE-related posts:

- [Why are there no line numbers in the code listings?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7119/168244)
- [How to add line numbers to the code lines?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216914/168244)

Comment: how about a button which does something similar to what I found here: http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2007/12/source-code-line-numbers-and-javascript/

Comment: @naphaneal: This would have to be something that garners network-wide appeal, and is therefore typically suited for [meta.se] rather than some child-meta. However, it's already been raised/addressed there, so there's not much more one can do other than continue the discussion there.